# Android SDK is not installed with Android Studio IDE

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

so I've downloaded the Android Studio IDE from the official website, installed, and run it. When I try to create a new project this is what I get:

[image]

Obviously I click on (open SDK manager):

[image]

I then click on (Edit):

[image]

At first, the directory `/Android/SDK` was totally missing, so I added it manually by creating the two folders `Android` and `SDK` in the directory `C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\`  . Which led to the line "target folder is neither empty nor does it point to an existing SDK installation". The SDK manager was never Installed, I couldn't find it in the directory mentioned. Therefore, I downloaded the SDK tools and put it in the directory specified, but that didn't work. An SO thread has suggested that I don't have enough storage space for the SDK, but I have almost 31GB of empty space on my C:\ drive, another one has suggested that I have a proxy/ http problem but I don't think that this is the problem here since I've downloaded the IDE with no problems.

After I hit `next` this is what I get:

[image]

Now how could the SDK could be is up to date while there isn't any SDK to be seen?

I'd appreciate some help, have a nice day

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and re-installing Android Studio? That's one good solution to such problems... there are too many possible reasons to guess..

Comment: @SerjArdovic I've installed it four times, I even downloaded the .zip version, nothing seems to be working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this error may arise when your sdk folder not a 'platforms' folder and you must make an empty folder and rename it to 'platforms'. platforms folder must be in the sdk folder.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded SDK installers alone and solved the problem. One site to get the installers is: [SDK Installer](https://android-sdk.uptodown.com/windows?)

Comment: Download android sdk from official website [Link](https://developer.android.com/studio?gclid=Cj0KCQjw8IaGBhCHARIsAGIRRYrFcYlMPT_ruqJ9tablDoTVgKC47yeaiL0Hytpluro4HGgLICC2EoEaAk56EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).

Comment: Then go to Android Studio File -> Settings - > Appearance and Behavior -> System Settnigs -> Android SDK. Here you can provide the path of your downloaded SDK.